# Why time of session with jwt-auth is 1 hour from time of login?

Tags: laravel, jwt

In laravel 7 backend rest api app I use jwt-auth and I have a problem that on login
I can work in frontend part but in 1 hour I got TOKEN_EXPIRED error.

1) I tried to set time of session bigger, but failed. On development stage I need time of session more 1 hour.
Moving on live I will set time of session 30 minutes.

2) I expected that session bigger is 1 hour from last request of logged user to backend, but not from login

I have refresh method implemented below, but looks like refresh does not work...

app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\library\CheckValueType;
use App\Settings;
use Auth;
use Config;
use DB;
use Validator;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\UserGroup;
use App\Http\Resources\UserCollection;
use Avatar;
use Storage;

class AuthController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['login', 'register', 'activate']]);
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($token = $this->guard('api')->attempt($credentials)) {
            $loggedUser = $this->guard('api')->user();

            if ($loggedUser->status != 'A') {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], HTTP_RESPONSE_NOT_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }
            $loggedUser->last_logged = Carbon::now(config('app.timezone'));
            $loggedUser->save();

            $userGroupsCount = UserGroup
                ::getByUserId($loggedUser->id)
                ->count();
            if ($userGroupsCount == 0) {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], HTTP_RESPONSE_NOT_UNAUTHORIZED);
            }

            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], HTTP_RESPONSE_NOT_UNAUTHORIZED);
    }


    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json($this->guard('api')->user());
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard('api')->logout();
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard()->refresh());
    }

    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        $loggedUser = $this->guard()->user();

        $user_avatar_path = 'public/' . User::getUserAvatarPath($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar);
        $filenameData     = User::setUserAvatarProps($loggedUser->id, $loggedUser->avatar, true);
        $usersGroups = User::getUserGroupByUserId($loggedUser->id, false);

        return response()->json([
            'access_token'     => $token,
            'user'             => $loggedUser,
            'token_type'       => 'bearer',
            'user_avatar_path' => $user_avatar_path,
            'filenameData'     => $filenameData,
            'usersGroups'      => $usersGroups,
            'expires_in'       => $this->guard('api')->factory()->getTTL() * 999360 // I SET VERY BIG VALUE
        ]);
    }

    public function guard()
    {
        return \Auth::Guard('api');
    }
```

In  /config/auth.php :

```
<?php

return [


    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'jwt',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 99360, // I SET BIG VALUE
            'throttle' => 98860,
        ],
    ],


    'password_timeout' => 10800,  // I SET BIG VALUE
```

In app/Exceptions/Handler.php I have:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{

    if ($exception instanceof UnauthorizedHttpException) {
        if ($exception->getPrevious() instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
            \Log::info( '-2 UnauthorizedHttpException TokenExpiredException::' ); // I SEE THIS ERROR LOGGED
            return response()->json(['error' => 'TOKEN_EXPIRED'], $exception->getStatusCode());
```

I have :

```
"laravel/framework": "^7.0",
"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0",
```

What is wrong  in my config?

**MODIFIED :**

I added file 
app/Http/Middleware/JwtMiddleware.php with content and 1 line of error logging :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;

class JwtMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            if (! $user = $this->auth->parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Invalid User.')]);
            }
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            try {
                $refreshed = $this->auth->refresh($this->auth->getToken());
                $user = $this->auth->setToken($refreshed)->toUser();
                header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $refreshed);
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Could not generate refresh token')]);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            \Log::info( '-1 JwtMiddleware$e->getMessage() ::' . print_r(  $e->getMessage(), true  ) );

            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Invalid request')]);
        }

        return  $next($request);
    }
}
```

and I added in file app/Http/Kernel.php :

```
   ...
    protected $middleware = [
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\JwtMiddleware::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class
    ];
   ...

and running the page site is broken and I see lines in log :
[2020-05-27 17:08:33] local.INFO: -1 JwtMiddleware$e->getMessage() ::The token could not be parsed from the request  
[2020-05-27 17:08:33] local.INFO: -1 JwtMiddleware$e->getMessage() ::The token could not be parsed from the request  
[2020-05-27 17:08:33] local.INFO: -1 JwtMiddleware$e->getMessage() ::The token could not be parsed from the request
```

Can it be some conflict with code of app/Http/Controllers/API/AuthController.php ?
How can it be fixed ?

**MODIFIED #2:**
Thanks ! I fixed the error and in .env I added lines :

```
JWT_TTL=20 # 20 minutes
JWT_REFRESH_TTL=20160 # 2 weeks
```

and clearing cache I logged again and as result while working in the app I did 
not logout any 20 minutes, but when I left the app opened without working with it
for period about 30 minutes I could continue working without log ou, as I expected.
Are these other options ?

**MODIFIED #3:**
In client part of my vuejs file I fave a request interceptors in src/App.vue:

```
created() {
    let self = this
    this.$http.interceptors.response.use(undefined, function (error) {

        return new Promise(function (/*resolve, reject*/) {
            if (typeof error.response.status !== 'undefined' && error.response.status === 401) {
                self.$store.dispatch('logout')  // DEBUGGING
                self.showPopupMessage('Access', 'Not authorized !', 'warn')
                let splitted0 = self.getSplitted(error.response.config.url, '/login', 0)

                if (splitted0 == '') { // not move from login page
                    self.$router.push('/login')   // DEBUGGING
                }
            }

            if (typeof error.response.status !== 'undefined') {
                if (error.response.status === 401) {
                    self.$store.dispatch('logout') // DEBUGGING
                    self.showPopupMessage('Access', 'Not authorized !', 'warn')
                    self.$router.push('/login')  // DEBUGGING
                }
            }

            throw error
        })
    })


}, //  created() {
```

I catch 401 error in it and wonder is it possible to catch the request from the server

```
header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $refreshed);
```

and to write to new access_token value from $refreshed?
But how can I catch it? But some special return request code?

Thanks!

Comment: After changing such configurations, it's often a good practise to run `php artisan config:clear` & `php artisan cache:clear` to see the changes in effect.

Comment: sure I did it. Even with composer install command (removing /verdor) and composer dump-autoload .

Comment: sure there are other ways to do it and you can try them of you have any problem with this . But if it is working then why you need another way.

Comment: Which another way?  Please give a reference? Is parameter JWT_TTL must work as expect above?

Comment: @mstdmstd Please see my updates, i have explained another way. But i would still suggest you stick to the first method. Are you facing any issues that way?

Comment: Thanks! I think that the decision for my case would be : generate a new refresh_token with each API request and update it in your frontend. Please details how can I do it ?

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED #3

Comment: @mstdmstd Check in the interceptor if the response header has a token, if yes then update the token in local storage.

Comment: how can I make this checking? Has it some code to catch? Please give example to similar checking

Answer (score 2):

go to ---> config/jwt.php
You can do this

```
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 1440)
```

OR in Controller

```
$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials, ['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDays(7)->timestamp]);
```

OR

```
config()->set('jwt.ttl', 60*60*7);
```

OR

```
Config::set('jwt.ttl', 60*60*7);
```

Comment: I have already implemented these options. Please check MODIFIED #3

Answer (score 2):

You should have a `config/jwt.php` file. If you do not have this yet, run:

```php
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider"
```

Within that file, you can see several properties that refer to `.env` variables, being:

- 'ttl' (env = 'JWT_TTL')
- 'refresh_ttl' (env = 'JWT_REFRESH_TTL')

Also, you might want to add `'refresh'` to that `jwt.auth` middleware exception list because else it will not work when you call the `refresh()` function in the controller.

**HOWEVER, there are some important things to note here in this package:**

#### Authentication TTLs are linked together

I believe that you can pretty much disregard the `ttl` property, since its the `refresh_ttl` that actually defines how long your JWTs are valid, based on this analogy:

> The locksmith (auth provider) gives you a Red Key (the JWT). That key allows you to open the Red Door (use your backend). The key snaps in half automatically after 5 minutes (TTL = 5min). However you can go back to the locksmith with your broken key and he will replace it for the duration of 2 weeks (Refresh TTL = 2w).

You can basically call the `auth/refresh` endpoint with your expired JWT and it will refresh it until the Refresh-TTL has expired.

See also [this issue on github][1] which also explains why you need to add the `refresh` function to not have `jwt.auth` middleware in front of it.

#### You do not save any DB calls when using the JWT as provided by this package

My initial thought was that it could save me a roundtrip to the database because the user object would be signed and ready inside the JWT.

I've used this package in several projects now and I came to the conclusion that it is somewhat of a glorified session cookie. In `tymon/jwt`, the `sub` claim simply equals `1` (or whichever user ID is referenced here).

This means you need to either...

- ... (default) let `tymon/jwt` do the work which simply retrieves the user from the database and applies it to your auth provider so `Auth::user()` etc will work.

OR

- ... add a claim yourself with a full user object and modify this package in various places. This could save you DB calls since this object will be part of and signed within your JWT. It causes more JWT bytes to send though on each request, but you can basically take the given object for granted (i.e. accept it as it is received) and use it. You can then also add permissions/roles this way so those do not need to get retrieved from the database as well. This setup DOES mean that when changing any permissions in your database, you'd have to wait for a new JWT being refreshed in order to see those changes.

Comment: I try to follow it. Could you please to point at auth/refresh endpoint  implementation ?

Comment: @mstdmstd there's documentation here https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth . Its worth your time to read through some of that i.c.w. https://jwt.io/introduction/

Answer (score 1):

- You need to add middleware and check if token expired.
- If expired check what is the generation time to check if you should generate a new token or not. Think of this as a refresh token expire time. you can skip this step if you want to generate a refresh token without any time validations.
- Now if all ok generate a new token and send it in the header/ body as you wish and store that in your frontend application.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Http\Middleware\BaseMiddleware;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;

class JwtMiddleware extends BaseMiddleware
{
    /**
   * Handle an incoming request.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  \Closure  $next
   * @return mixed
   */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            if (! $user = $this->auth->parseToken()->authenticate()) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Invalid User.')]);
            }
        } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
            try {
                $refreshed = $this->auth->refresh($this->auth->getToken());
                $user = $this->auth->setToken($refreshed)->toUser();
                header('Authorization: Bearer ' . $refreshed);
            } catch (JWTException $e) {
                return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Could not generate refresh token')]);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => __('Invalid request')]);
        }

        return  $next($request);
    }
}
```

UPDATES:

This is the method i followed in my recent Ionic/ Angular APP. And it works fine. There are ways that i have done before, but it is hard to explain, let me know when you have any problem following.

- You generate a token and a refresh_token both when you successfully login and send both the tokens to your front end APP and save it there in local storage.
- For all the protected APIs you now have to send the token and the refresh_token.
- In the API side validate the token and if expired check if refresh_token is valid or expired. If expired you are logged out.
- If refresh_token is valid generate a new token and refresh_token and send it to the front end and store it there.
- There is one problem with this method, the login session should be active as long as the user is using the APP. So let's say your JWT_REFRESH_TTL is 1 day and the user is using just before 24Hrs, it will work before 24Hr are passed but it will not work just after 1 min as both token and refresh_token both will expire.
- To overcome this you can generate a new refresh_token with each API request and update it in your frontend.

Generally, the JWT_TTL should be very short like 5 mins or so and JWT_REFRESH_TTL should be the session active time.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose to add it in app/Http/Kernel.php file in protected $middleware = [ ? Has it meaning it must be first or last in this group?

Comment: Add in protected $routeMiddleware. It can be added as the last item, it does not matter.

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED :

Comment: Please add these two lines in .ENV file and clear cache and try again. 
 JWT_TTL=1440  JWT_REFRESH_TTL=2880

Basically you need to give a higher JWT_REFRESH_TTL then JWT_TTL else refresh method will not work and give an exception. 
Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED # 2:

Answer (score 1):

try this in your login

```
if ($token = $this->guard('api')->attempt($credentials,['exp' => Carbon\Carbon::now()->addHours(2)->timestamp])) {

}
```

Or You Can chnage the `ttl` in `config/jwt`

Let Me know if it Helps!

Comment: Thanks! Helpful to set time of session bigger.

Answer (score 0):

As other people suggested to you, go to your `config/jwt.php` and modify the token expiration limit:

```
// ...
'ttl' => env('JWT_TTL', 3600)
```

**Important:** After changing that, **clear your config cache**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Also, note that previous generated tokens will have their own claims so it's likely that those tokens won't follow the modified rule.

### Side note

As an alternative to implementing the JWT yourself, you could make use of Sanctum, a new first-party Laravel package. Check the [SPA mode](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum#spa-authentication) in the [Sanctum documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum).